# How to use the if statement (JavaScript) with the select tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried many ways to do this but this isn't right:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Select</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="test">
            <option value="one">1</option>
            <option value="two">2</option>
            <option value="three">3</option>
        </select>
        <script>
        if (test=="two") {
            document.write("two!");
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to let something appear on the screen if the user chooses "two" but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might help you

```
<select name="test" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="one">1</option>
<option value="two">2</option>
<option value="three">3</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    if(x == "two"){
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    }
}
</script>
```

Have a look
http://jsfiddle.net/snsbbytw/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to listen to the change event of the select.

```
document.getElementsByName("test")[0].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
   if (e.target.value === "two") { // not sure if it's e.targe.value, and this might not work in all browsers
       document.write("two!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the onChange event

```
<select name="test" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
```

Avoid using document.write since it will replace the document output.. And of course, avoid use inline scripting ;)

Comment: console.log output only on console not on webpage. while user want to show the value on webpage.